# How to make color long last on Navigation Bar on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, navigationbar

I would like to build a bottom navigation bar, with selected icon item showing a customized color and unselected icon items in white. But after I set up a setState() function for the hook that indicates the item index, the click only makes the color show an instant and disappears. However, when I use `Colors`, the pre-set system palette colors, for example `Colors.amber[800]`, it works out fine and the color will STAY. Instead when I use my own color, it will FLASH. What is the probable cause for the situation and what is the fix?

Here's my code and issue demo GIF.

```
class _MyRootPageState extends State<MyRootPage> {
  int currentPage = 0;
  List<Widget> pages = const [
    HomePage(),
    SettingsPage(),
    SavedPage(),
    ShoppingCartPage(),
    MessagePage()
  ];

  void setCurrentPage(int index) {
    // setState() refreshes the component tree
    setState(() {
      currentPage = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Pink Blue'),
      ),
      body: pages[currentPage],
      bottomNavigationBar:BottomNavigationBar(
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), label:"",),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label:""),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.list), label:""),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined), label:""),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.mail), label:""),
        ],
        onTap: setCurrentPage,
        currentIndex: currentPage,
        selectedItemColor: const Color(0xE10098),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing leading FF which corresponds to opacity or alpha of color in your custom color
`selectedItemColor: const Color(0xE10098)`
it should be `0xFFE10098` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you use color hashcode than you need to add before hashcode `0XFF` and than add your color code.

Syntax : `Color(0XFF<color code>)`

You can try this

```
selectedItemColor: const Color(0XFFE10098),
```